# how can i use history push in useEffect react

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to implement the `history.push` prototype inside useEffect hook . this is how I did it :

```
useEffect(()=>
{
reset()
props.history.push('/')
},[signUpSuccess])
```

I have tried to import useHistory , yet its no longer supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, useHistory is no longer supported. It has been replace by useNavigate in react-router version 6. You can use it like this:

```
const history= useNavigate()

history('/')
```

instead of:

```
const history = useHistory()
history.push('/')
```

EDIT CONCERNING THE AUTOMATIC REDIRECT ON CLICK

The React documentation states:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

This means that the code inside the useEffect hook will be executed each time the component will be rendered/updated.

Comment: This is not an ES6 change, it's a react-router version 6 change.

Comment: now there is a new problem, whenever i try to access the page where i've implemented method  , the page will redirect automatically